# UISegmentedControl unrecognized selector sent

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, unrecognized-selector

I've a part of my application that show in a MapView the possibilty to change the map type.

```
UISegmentedControl *mapType = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                    @[NSLocalizedString(@"MapTypeStandardLabelText", @""),
                                      NSLocalizedString(@"MapTypeHybridLabelText", @""),
                                      NSLocalizedString(@"MapTypeSatelliteLabelText", @"")]];

[self.view addSubview:mapType];
_mapTypeSegmentedControl = mapType;

_mapTypeSegmentedControl.center = self.view.center;
CGRect segmentedFrame = _mapTypeSegmentedControl.frame;
segmentedFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height -
                            _mapTypeSegmentedControl.frame.size.height - 20;
_mapTypeSegmentedControl.frame = segmentedFrame;
_mapTypeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = _selectedSegmentIndex;
[_mapTypeSegmentedControl addTarget:self
                             action:@selector(changeMapType:)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

When I tried to press a new type of the map showed, I get the following error:

```
2014-03-05 12:12:51.524 iBlues Pocket[31057:70b] -[UISegmentedControl modalPresentationStyle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20497250
2014-03-05 12:12:51.528 iBlues Pocket[31057:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UISegmentedControl modalPresentationStyle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20497250'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x038355e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x032ff8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x038d2903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0382590b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x038254ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   UIKit                               0x00d048c3 -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 232
    6   UIKit                               0x11c46f1f -[UIViewControllerAccessibility(SafeCategory) presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 71
    7   UIKit                               0x00d0661f -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 130
    8   iBlues Pocket                       0x000a022d -[MapOptionsViewController changeMapType:] + 109
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0331181f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    ...
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Can anyone help me?

The `changeMapType:` method:

```
- (void)changeMapType:(id)sender {     
    [self presentViewController:sender animated:NO completion:nil];          
    if (_delegate != nil) {         
        [_delegate didCompleteOptionsSelection:sender];     
    } 
}
```

Comment: can you show `changeMapType:` method?

Comment: `- (void)changeMapType:(id)sender {
    [self presentViewController:sender animated:NO completion:nil];
    
    if (_delegate != nil) {
        [_delegate didCompleteOptionsSelection:sender];
    }
}
`

Comment: @umpire274, Long code and errors are hard to read in comments so in these cases please edit the question instead.  Thanks.  Also, you understand that in `changeMapType:`, the `sender` is the `UISegmentedControl`?

Answer (score 0):

It gives error Because you are sending the UISegment object in `presentViewController:` method,

SO  try self

```
 UIViewController *vc =// Your viewController to present 
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

And if it is in viewDidLoad than put it in viewDidAppear  method.

Comment: No way. I got the error `2014-03-05 13:33:07.332 iBlues Pocket[66797:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <MapOptionsViewController: 0xd11cdb0>.'`

Comment: OK. explain better. This view is called from a parent view that contain the MapView. When I click on right-low corner of the map is show a view with the UISegmentControl in this case.

Comment: The call on parent view is `- (void)changeMapType {
    MapOptionsViewController *mapOptionsViewController = [[MapOptionsViewController alloc] init];
    mapOptionsViewController.delegate = self;
    [mapOptionsViewController setSelectedSegmentIndex:_currentMapType];
    mapOptionsViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
    [self presentViewController:mapOptionsViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
`

Comment: I dident get your flow,, please explain what exactly you have implemented, i give answer why your app crash , now this is another issue.

Comment: It is the same issue. I've an UIViewController (A) where I construct the Map View and at the right-bottom corner I put a page curl image to open another UIViewController (B) where is the UISegmentedControl definition.

Comment: In the A view I've a `NSInteger _currentMapType` that contain the current map type. When I call B View and choose the new map type, I change the `NSInteger _currentMapType` in the A View.

Comment: In the A ViewController I've defined the `- (void)didCompleteOptionsSelection:(id)sender` MapViewController Delegate that change the map type. And that's it. 'Viruss mca' how can contact you in private?

Comment: @umpire274: no need for contact in private, Update your question , you will get proper answer, ok.